# Javascript-error when using optimizations on bundling

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, bundling-and-minification

I'm encountering a strange issue after bundling my javascript together using .net bundling setting `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

Below is the part of the emitted file which throws the error (simplified version):

```
var somVar = new b({
        searchUrl: "/someUrl",
        data: n => {
            query: n.term,
            page: n.page,
            teamId: this.props.teamId,
            season: this.props.season
        },
        resultFormat: this.formatState,
        resultSort: this.sortResults,
        onSelect: this.handlePlayerSelect
    });
```

However, in line 5 it tells me `Unexpected token :`. I don't get the point why. Maybe I'm overlooking something fundamental here.
Without optimizations the scripts do run normally.

In the non-optimized version the part looks this:

```
var someVar = new Select2({
        searchUrl: "/someUrl",
        data: (params) => {
            return {
                query: params.term,
                page: params.page,
                teamId: this.props.teamId,
                season: this.props.season
            };
        },
        resultFormat: this.formatState,
        resultSort: this.sortResults,
        onSelect: this.handlePlayerSelect
    })
```

This is the original typescript-version:

```
new Select2({
    searchUrl: "/someUrl",
    data: (params: Select2QueryOptions) => {
        return {
            query: params.term,
            page: params.page,
            teamId: this.props.teamId,
            season: this.props.season
        }
    },
    resultFormat: this.formatState,
    resultSort: this.sortResults,
    onSelect: this.handlePlayerSelect
} as ISelect2Props)
```

This is part of an array which is passed as kind of sub-module into a base-module, so no variable where it is bound to here.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/17661035/34092 ?

Comment: Could it be that the simplified version is never explicitly asked to return anything?

Comment: @MattLuccasPhaureJensen What exactly do you mean by not asked to return anything? Who should have asked? I've added the original TypeScript part as well to the question.

Comment: ```new Select2({
    searchUrl: "/someUrl",
    data: (params: Select2QueryOptions) => ({
            query: params.term,
            page: params.page,
            teamId: this.props.teamId,
            season: this.props.season
        }),
    resultFormat: this.formatState,
    resultSort: this.sortResults,
    onSelect: this.handlePlayerSelect
} as ISelect2Props)``` is this working on TS no return just ()?

Comment: @zxxc I also tried playing around with copying `var self = this;` outside and passing in a `function(params: Select2QueryOptions) {return ...}`. ReSharper told me to convert it to lambda. Ended up in the exactly same code as you've posted. Unfortunately not working as well... So, yes. Works in TS but does not fix the bundling issue

Comment: Which internet browser do you use? Is this line is working in your browser ```var c=n=>{ a:1, b:n+2 }; c(5)``` ? In mine not (chrome) and it should be ```var c=n=>({ a:1, b:n+2 }); c(5)``` Maybe it's optimizer issue, and simpler would be to create separate function for returning data. Did you try to change version of your minifier?

Comment: @zxxc As it turned out the changed syntax did work for me. Unfortunately the minified file is a one-liner so I thought it would not work. But I realized that on another code-file I had the same issue (copy & paste bug). While this fixes the issue for me I'm still not sure what went wrong at all. Leave an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it gets optimized in a way that doesn't work but this should urn.

```
var somVar = new b({
    searchUrl: "/someUrl",
    data: n => {
        return {
            query: n.term,
            page: n.page,
            teamId: this.props.teamId,
            season: this.props.season
        };
    },
    resultFormat: this.formatState,
    resultSort: this.sortResults,
    onSelect: this.handlePlayerSelect
});
```

Note that i only changed the way it returns the data with an explicit return call.