# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < On Chrome

Tags: json, google-chrome

I know this question has been asked many times but I can't find similarity with my issue. I'm getting this error only in Chrome, in every other browser everything is ok. I return data with JSON in several places but since my code works in other browsers I assume nothing is wrong with it.
Chrome doesn't show me where is error (in my code) it shows me these errors:

[image]

This is how I use JSON:

```
$.post("getData.php", {'id' : id}, function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
.
.
.

... some mysqli query
$data = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode($data);
```

So I don't see a problem here, can someone help me with this.

Comment: What's the status code, 200 OK? If not, you might be getting the html for the error response and it will not parse and generate that kind of error. Probably something with your SQL query.

Comment: Everything is 200 OK, and in some places I get 200 Found. As I said, it works perfectly in Firefox, I don't see a reason why would I get some error if it works in Firefox

Comment: Have you tried to turn off AdBlock and test it?

Comment: @Mario Yes, I tried, but it's the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: For me this was because of incorrect path in the `src` attribute of the  `script` tags at the end of my file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` using @Mario answer but that was only part of my problem. Another problem is, javascript doesn't get any data from PHP file. That was solved using this code, inside PHP file: `header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");`
This answer is found on this link, where I opened another question to solve this issue: [Can't receive json data from PHP in Chrome and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599150/cant-receive-json-data-from-php-in-chrome-and-opera/19599377?noredirect=1#19599377)

Comment: I had this problem twice so far. The first time the solution was to replace all the `echo`s in the `.php` file into 1 array with different entries. The second time (just now), it was simpler: I had to delete the comment in top of my `.php` file ( The file started like this: `<!-- comment... --> <?php....?>`). So this is where the `<` was coming from.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. What was Mario's answer, I can't find it.

Answer (score 17):

You can check your Network (console) and See the answer from the Server ... The "<" will be the first letter of your response. Something like "<"undefined index XY in line Z>"

Comment: Can you provide an live example?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't. I noticed it gives me error for first < sign. So currently first < sign is in <!DOCTYPE html>, if I delete < then it gives me same error but instead < it says ! is unexpected token.

Comment: No... If you recieve a response from the Server which jquery can't parse you will See uncought errors like that... .. Many Seen errors also "o" or "u" and this letter is the first sign of the response jquery cant parse....

Answer (score 8):

My solution to this is pretty unbelievable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataLayer.js?v=1"></script>
```

The filename in the src attribute needed to be lowercase:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/datalayer.js?v=1"></script>
```

and that somewhat inexplicably fixed the problem.

In both cases the reference was returning 404 for testing.

Comment: I had the same problem so changed the file name into another name and it worked. My file name did not have capital letter anywhere.

Comment: This fixed it for me. The strange thing is that it was working with a capital letter for quite some time - then all of a sudden threw the error.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error ("Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" ) at these two lines when testing a sample application .

```
<script type = "text/javascript"  src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript"  src="kuma-gauge.jquery.js"></script>
```

After a control, I realized that, local file locations are not correct and my local server app returns default page as the result. Client app can find the files but the founded files are default page, not the *.js files. So I receive Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I changed to orginal location on the intenet andit solved.

```
<script type = "text/javascript"  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript"  src="//www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-Animated-Gauges-Using-jQuery-Raphael-js-kumaGauge/js/kuma-gauge.jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: This happened to me when my scripts were in the subdirectory `stuff/scripts` but I went to the URL `stuff/whatever/` instead of `stuff/whatever`. Because `stuff/whatever/scripts` didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

To override the error that you might experience in Chrome (and probably in Safari), try to set the Ajax parameter as `dataType: "json"`. Then you shouldn't call `parseJSON()` on the `obj` because the response you'll get comes deserialized.

Comment: I don't see this error anymore but I don't receive any data from server, although this same code works in Firefox: http://pastebin.com/md2GC4CA

Comment: What kind of data are you expecting from the ajax response - html, JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I have commented my this code : `// $('#description').val('<?php echo $_POST['description']; ?>');` and I got that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: route_to_main_page");
```

I've encountered this problem while having a custom 404 error handling file. Instead of throwing some html content it was suppose to redirect to the main page url. It worked well.

Then I used this as a skeleton for a next project, therefore not changing the "route_to_main_page" actually on the new project (different URL) became a "route_to_external_url" so any 404 errors within your code (missing css stylesheets, js libraries) would return the "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**".

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue when I moved some of the js files into folders then deployed into production, after some struggle I found out that the js files were not actually got deployed to production. So

1. make sure that the file for which the error is shown does exist in 
   the server
2. the path given is correct

So, In the absence of js file, the server then server responds with as below

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <someTag />
        <AnotherTag />
    </html>
```

Thats why we get ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <***

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the resource you're trying to request is under restricted access via your web app configuration, i.e. user must be logged for the application to serve the file.

Try adding this to your Web.Config file (**this is for .NET applications**):

```
<location path="js/resourcefile.js">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

You can place it anywhere before the closing *configuration* tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to perform Ajax file upload or something similar, you have to get rid of displaying further HTML after printing your ajax response text. Probably that gives this error message. If you are using PHP framework you have to follow framework syntax to end the application. If you are coding pure PHP, you can use 'exit' after your ajax response text.

Hope this will help save some ones' time on finding solution for this. :) happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
$.post({ 
         url = 'getData.php',  
         data : { 'id' id } , 
         dataType : 'text'
       });
```

This way ajax will not try to parse the data into json or similar

Answer (score 0):

Seems everyone has difference experiences from this and therfore solutions as well :) This is my "story".

My thing came from a validate.php file fetched with ajax. The output was meant to be :

```
$response['status'] = $status;
$response['message'] = $message;
$response['param'] = $param;

echo json_encode($response);
```

And the error that cause the "Unexpected token <" error was simply that in some cases $message hadn't been declared (but only $status and $param). So, added this in the beginning of the code.

```
$message = ''; // Default value, in case it doesn't get set later on.
```

So I guess, those "little things" may in this scenario big of quite importance. So be sure to really check your code and making it bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. My problem was caused from shifting around my project directory, and failing to adjust the path to my static files on the server to reflect the new path (i.e. was `./src/public` but should have been `./public`).

Answer (score 0):

The only place it worked for me is when I place the scripts in `public` folder where my `index.html` resides and then placing these `<script type="text/javascript" src="test/test.js"></script>` inside `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, host had enabled `iisnode` at my `web.config` file so I've commented.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <!-- <add name="iisnode" path="*.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" /> -->
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```