# Can't receive json data from PHP in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have problems with JSON on Chrome and Opera for several days, I managed to fix some errors but now I'm stuck and can't find a way out. I create some array in PHP, encode it in JSON and send it to javascript file where I process it further. In Firefox everything is ok, but in Chrome and Opera `$.post()` function is never called. I assume it stop working when javascript needs to receive JSON data. Your help is so much needed.

This is my javascript function:

```
var updateGroup = function(id){

    $("#unshareTable").html("");
    passID = id;
    $.post("getData.php", {'id' : id}, function(obj){
        globalColor = obj.color;
        $("#updateGroupTitle").val(obj.title);
        $("#updateColorpickerHolder").css("background-color", obj.color);
        $("#updateColorHex").html(obj.color);
        var color2 = lighterColor(obj.color, .4); 
        $("#updateColorHex2").html(color2);
        $("#updateGroupDescription").html(obj.description);
        $("#unshareTable").append("<tr id='firstRowUnshare'><td>Username</td><td>Option</td></tr>");
        $.post("getUnshareData.php", {'title' : obj.title}, function(obj1){
            var length = obj1.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                $("#unshareTable").append("<tr><td class='unshareUsername'>"+obj1[i].username+"</td><td><label class='unshareOneButton'>Unshare</label></td></tr>");
            }
        }, "json");
    }, "json");
    $(".updateGroupDiv").fadeIn(300);
}
```

and simple PHP script

```
<?php 
    $id = clean($_POST['id']);

    $query = $mysqli->query("select * from groups where id_group = '$id'");
    $data = $query->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Also in Chrome I get these error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getURL' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRequest' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP, add the following to the first line (after your opening tag)

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
```

It specifies the response as JSON

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me. Just for the record I had to add session_start(); in my PHP file, don't know why but it doesn't work without it.