# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in windows only

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors

on checkout from SVN all of my Javascript files load with errors on the first line

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I've read this thread [Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

and that doesn't seem to be the issue
All of my js is loaded externally. A sample import line
'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
```

What puzzles me is this only happens on Windows!

Comment: What exactly is in the first few lines of that script?

Comment: The error is inside the JavaScript code, not in this HTML snippet you posted.