# Same code does not work on different URL/page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ok, this will be long...

I am making mini CMS, which has add post, edit post, delete post. All works good, but edit post. On page for adding post I have same code as on page for editing, but that same code does not work on edit post page. I used ajax and php combination for geting images for dir (That part does not work). So my dir structure is like this:

```
/public_html
   /admin
       /posts
           /ajaxphp
               /images.php
           /images
           /js
               /images.js
           /add.php
           /edit.php
```

So in my `posts` folder I have `add.php, edit.php, ajaxphp dir and in that dir images.php`.

My urls are like this:

```
example.com/admin/posts/add.php              - For post adding
example.com/admin/posts/edit.php             - For edit
example.com/admin/posts/images               - Dir for images
example.com/admin/posts/ajaxphp/images.php   - Code for geting images
```

Here is my code on **edit.php**:

```
<?php
   require_once '../../core/init.inc.php';
?>

<form id="form" method="POST" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title*"></p>
    <p><textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">

    <p><a id="featured" href="#">Featured image</a></p>

    <img style="display: none; width:120px; height: 75px" id="featured_prev" src=""/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="featured_image">         
        <div><a id="upload_ref" href="#">Upload</a> | <a id="choose_ref" href="#">Choose</a></div>

        <div id="upload" class="featured_hidden">
            <div id="plupload">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="choose" class="featured_hidden">
             // HERE I HAVE TO GET IMAGES....
        </div>
    <p><input type="submit" name='publish' value="Publish"/></p>
</form>
<script src="<?php echo $site_admin_url; ?>posts/js/images.js"></script>
```

Explanation: When someone clicks on choose that activates my JS code **images.js**. And that code should get images with php and return it to page. It works but on add.php page, and on edit.php does not work...
So I click on some post to edit: `example.com/admin/posts/edit/title-of-post`
I think that '`title-of-post`' is problem but don't know.
Ok, when I click '**choose**' it gives this error in console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <          title-of-post:2

Here is my **images.php** file:

```
 <?php
 $directory = "../images/";
 $images = glob($directory . "*.*");

 echo json_encode($images);
 ?>
```

And my **images.js**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#choose_ref", function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $("#choose").empty();
    $('#image_loading').show();
    $.get( "ajaxphp/images.php", {} )
        .done(function( data ) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
                if(obj[i].indexOf("blank.gif") > -1)
                    continue;
                else
                    $("#choose").prepend("<div class='featured_image_div'>" +
                                         "<input value='posts/" + obj[i] + "' type='checkbox' name='featured' class='check_featured'>" +
                                         "<img class='images' src='posts/" + obj[i] + "' />" +
                                         "</div>");
        });

    $('#image_loading').hide();
});
```

Same code is on **add.php** and it uses same **images.php** and **images.js** but on add.php it works, I don't know why does not work on **edit.php**.. Maybe because of url...

I hope I explained well..

Thank you!

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630029/980615