# <!DOCTYPE HTML> unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, deployment, firebase

Im making an AngularJS+AngularFire+Firebase Application.
My problem is same decribed in this post [(check post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529446/unexpected-token-in-first-line-of-html)

but solution there did not help me.
My firebase json is set as follows

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I waas trying to handle browser refresh, thats why I set destination to index.html, I have deployed my app on firebase on this link https://blinding-fire-7418.firebaseapp.com/

When I click on GotoHome then New page open up and then I click on browser refresh button it produces  error.
Actually when I browser refresh, `firebase` unable to find specified URL so `firebase` rewrites URL to index.html, while loading index.html again it gives below error and contents of `angular.min.js` are replaced by contents of index.html.

```
angular.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-route.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angularfire.min.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ angularfire.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ angularfire.min.js:12
App.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

this is index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="sampleApp">
<head>
    <title>My new Project</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

my project structure for Scripts folder is below
[image]

Comment: I think the problem could be with the paths which you had use din your index.html `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/App.js"></script>` once you are in `/customer/home` your firebase server is giving HTML response for js request.