# Problems trying to import a .js file in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Hello friends I'm having problems trying to use some functions that I have in two .js file. I already tried putting  base_url(); and the location of the file, I also added the 'url' in the config.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/pdf.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/pdf.worker.js" ></script>
```

I have the file in folder called: js

ERROR I GET ON THE GOOGLE CHROME CONSOLE:

GET http://[::1]/registro/js/pdf.worker.js net::ERR_ABORTED

**EDITED**
CONSOLE ERROR
[image]

Comment: Move js dir outside `application` directory. It has to reside next to `index.php` file. Location of `index.php` front controller is `base_url()` by config.

Comment: I'm gonna try that

Comment: I did it but now I'm having another error in the console. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < –

Comment: Good newsis that file is found in this location. Check the line in code where error is and edit your question with posting several lines around error line.

Comment: Done, I just edited the question and also I uploaded a picture with the error. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Click `Console` tab in Chrome. Left to `Source` what is in image for now.

Comment: Done, check it please

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529446/unexpected-token-in-first-line-of-html) if applicable or c/p error in google and check those SOF links.

Comment: Need more specific your question and where is js folder

Answer (score 1):

The request `http://[::1]` points to a common error - `$config['base_url']` MUST be set correctly. An empty string will not work. The entry in `/application/config/config.php` should look something like this.

```
 $config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";
```

Note the protocol `http://` and a trailing `/` must be included.

Comment: I did it but now I'm having another error in the console.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

Edit /application/config/config.php file

Remove this line
`$config['base_url'] = '';`


Rdd this code in config.php file

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Edit /application/config/autoload.php file.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```