# ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT when running PWA server

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I've recently been looking into building a PWA, using angular 6 and Node.js, and have been following the tutorial found [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/09/pwa-angular-6/)
. I have followed the steps up until the lighthouse portion and upon calling http-server I received a ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT when opening the server. Upon further inspection it appears that I am receiving an unexpected token error. This has led me to believe that there is an encapsulation issue in the program but I have been unable to find anything on the issue. Specifically, I believe the browser is interpreting some JS as HTML but I've had little luck finding where it is occurring. Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Thank you in advance.

I am able to serve the page up by using the command ng serve --open.

Looking in the developers tool it appears that it request is stalling. 
Changing the Authentication in the ISS manager resulted in the same issue.

References:

[Unexpected token < in first line of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529446/unexpected-token-in-first-line-of-html)

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3629

Final Project: 
https://github.com/techiediaries/angular-pwa

Answer (score 3):

Try to access to index.html directly, it might be related to https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/525

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue as well opening a PWA on localhost. As suggested by @ssh-uunen , i tried opening the url by appending index.html at the end and it opened eg: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html.

**The issue was due to http-server version** (https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/525).
**Try to upgrade/downgrade http-server version in your project.**

1.npm uninstall http-server

2.npm install http-server@0.12.0