# Why I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError '<' on html tag?

Tags: html, syntax, header, doctype

I am getting the following error on my page:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on line 1

Does anybody help me with this issue? Thanks

Here is the picture of it

[image]

Comment: Maybe it can be an error inside of some imported js or with the path of it.

Comment: Have a read through this, there could be **many** reasons this is happening: [Unexpected token < in first line of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529446/unexpected-token-in-first-line-of-html)

Comment: Yes i see, but mine points to index page, no js involved