# Unknown Browser Issues with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some weird issues getting with javascript running on a friend's machine. I have a form wizard that perform certain checks and operations. I use external `jquery` and  `bootstrap` libraries with a custom script also. The script works on all browsers I've test so far including `old IE` , however a friend reports the following errors when accessing the form url.

[image: chrome console error message]

The strange thing to me is every error is on line 1 and haven't touched any of the libraries.
External Library linking

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

custom `script.js` overview

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
...
// javascript code
...

});
```

Anything I should try or do?

Comment: That error is usually assoicated with an ajax call or the like that is expecting json as a response, but is instead getting an html document back

Comment: Look at the files, Looks like something is injecting HTML....

Comment: Mmm, I wonder if one of the js files starts with `<script>`.  Though I would expect that to fail on every browser.

Comment: Check the network tab of your dev tools. Does it show any error/unexpected result when fetching the resources?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt , everything gets fetch successfully, just this console error message

Comment: @epascarello , What possibly could be.. Kinda lost on injection

Comment: @Taplar I suspect each of those files starts with `<html>` and then contain a page that shows an error like 403 or 401. Maybe a 404. It's the most usual case here - returning an error page instead of JS.

Comment: @Taplar , I'm not actually using much of this libraries just to control the form wizard and style the page.

Comment: LOOK at the network response.... what is in the file.

Comment: @WanPeninsula Your question states that you're trying to get it to run on a friends machine, and that you are using external libraries.  However, your urls are not external urls.  They are relative path urls.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by getting it to run on your friends machine?

Comment: @Taplar , sorry about misinterpretation, I  downloaded the libraries and and linked them in the ```index``` file. The actual probelm here is, at my end, everything gets executed without errors and have tested in multiple browsers, but on the end of the friend testing, he gets thrown with this error in the console

Comment: So how is your friend testing it?  If you downloaded the files, then they are on your machine.  How is your friend testing it on their machine?

Comment: @Taplar, I sent a ```zipped``` archive over. He just unpacked and access it local on his browser

Comment: K, just double checking that you also sent him the files you downloaded.

Comment: have already. repacked and sent over more than ```5 times``` . same files in his directory

Comment: Check that your friend is referring the script files from the correct path (where he has copied the script files and mentioning that address in code).  Also check [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529506/6545996)