# JavaScript error in console. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-templates

I'm using [this gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/) for my project. But when I put the code in my page chrome console says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Here is code

```
<script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
    <div class="rg-image-wrapper">
        {{if itemsCount > 1}}
            <div class="rg-image-nav">
                <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>
                <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="rg-image"></div>
        <div class="rg-loading"></div>
        <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
            <div class="rg-caption" style="display:none;">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Anyone can help? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: try to reproduce your issue in jsfiddle and share that.