# Javascript String.prototype unexpected token

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

Apologies if this has been asked before but I couldn't find this specific issue.

I've been tasked with analysing a bit of highly obfuscated, and malicious, JS code. I'm trying to get it to run in a VM at the minute just to see exactly what it's up to but I'm getting a syntax error on the first line.

```
function String.prototype.x(){...
```

From Chrome's dev console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

The red squiggly line shows that the error is being thrown at the first dot (between String and prototype). To be honest, I don't know enough about JS to figure it out but I'm sure one of you lovely lot will know the answer. Why's it thrown and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer help?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630029/259889

Comment: you can't have a dot in function naming in this way, use `String.prototype.x = function(){}` instead

Comment: try String.prototype.x = function () { //your code }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is already a class (function with the inbuilt prototype methods) in JS , in order to create methods in its prototype chain you have use as below

```
String.prototype.reverse = function(){
  return this.split('').reverse().join()
}

"hello".reverse() // olleh
```

Comment: Cheers for that. Sorted out that error and now I'm coming across others revolving around constructors a little further down. But that's within the realm of the obfuscation. Excellent...