# Implementing 404 page in Django, but receiving error

Tags: python, html, css, django

[image: error image 1]

[image: error image 2]

I'm trying to implement my 404.html page into my django project, and coming across this error. Everything else is complete in my project, so I'm eager to get this last piece done! any help is greatly appreciated. included the 404.html and head_css.html file. please let me know if you need to see anything else.

Can anyone help with this?

My 404.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="404 Page not found">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<title>Codes For Anyone</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'themes/images/favicon.ico' %}">

<!-- Google icon -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

{% include 'landing/head_css.html' %}

</head>

<body class="body-custom body-404page">
    <div class="errorpage">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <h1 class="title">Page Not Found</h1>
                     <p class="description">The page you are looking for was moved, removed, <br>
                        renamed or might never existed.</p>
                     <div class="section-footer">
                        <a href="{% url 'referall:home' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Back To Homepage</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'referall:contact' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Report Error</a>
                     </div>
                </div><!-- content-primary -->
            </div><!-- container -->
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- chitika ad  code -->
            <div class=" container-fluid full-width-container contact">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    ( function() {
                    if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
                    var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"andrewdiemer","width":550,"height":250,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
                    var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
                    window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
                    document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
                    }());
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async></script>
            </div>
        <!-- end ad code -->
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts Starts -->
    {% include 'landing/javascript.html' %}
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    var sPath=window.location.pathname;
                    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    $(".pmd-sidebar-nav").each(function(){
                            $(this).find("a[href='"+sPage+"']").parents(".dropdown").addClass("open");
                            $(this).find("a[href='"+sPage+"']").parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-menu').css("display", "block");
                            $(this).find("a[href='"+sPage+"']").parents(".dropdown").find('a.dropdown-toggle').addClass("active");
                            $(this).find("a[href='"+sPage+"']").addClass("active");
                    });
            });
    </script>

    <!-- Scripts Ends -->

</body>
</html>
```

head_css.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<!-- Propeller css -->
<!-- build:[href] assets/css/ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/propeller.min.css' %}">
<!-- /build -->

<!-- Propeller date time picker css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'components/datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'components/datetimepicker/css/pmd-datetimepicker.css' %}" />

<!-- Propeller theme css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'themes/css/propeller-theme.css' %}" />

<!-- Propeller admin theme css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'themes/css/propeller-admin.css' %}">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: Posting your question as an image screenshot is like saying "please don't help me!"  Images don't allow us to cut-n-paste your code to try it ourselves, and are plain hard to read (I'm not going to give myself eyestrain trying to decipher that terrible screenshot.)

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks!.. I was dumb not to put that in initially. Updated now.

Comment: why `jquery` lib is a HTML page?

Comment: @sKwa, sorry don't quite understand your question.?

Comment: take a look on 1st img: tab with `jquery.min.js` is a HTML page and not js.

Comment: @sKwa, ah i see. But my code is html for the 404 page. How else should i declare this 404 page?

Comment: Does it shows content of HTML page or `jquery.min.js`? I thought tab shows `jquery.min.js` content.

Comment: @sKwa, show's content from HTML page, sorry .. not sure why is shows the jquery.min.js as the tab..

Comment: can you post `landing/head_css.html` header too(where css are defined)?

Comment: yup, will do .. one sec!

Comment: added :) see above

Comment: I think that problem is with static files. Who can open a chat?

Comment: @sKwa, don't have enough points to open up other chat for us. any advice for what to change?