# Unable to read properties of a property containing the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I'm having an issue trying to access the properties of an object, which has a reference property of another object. In other words, an object contained in other object.

After fetching the data from API calls like this one for example:https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=2352219608ed457fb3a12903193008&q=Helsinki my code get the response's data and set the hook's value: capitalWeather.

Anyways, the object has two attributes: location and current, which are also object type. Everytime I try to access any value from a reference, like accessing value of capitalWeather.location.region what I get is=

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'region' of undefined**

As expected, It also applies for any of the other attributes: name,country,lat,lon,tz_id,etc....

I don't understand why I'm getting a typeError, considering both are object types.

This is the code snippet where the error takes place:

```js
const Displayer = ({ country }) => {
    const [capitalWeather,setWeather]=useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=2352219608ed457fb3a12903193008&q=${country.capital}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Promise fullfiled, succesfully fetched data');
                setWeather(response.data);
            })
    }, [country.capital]);

    console.log(capitalWeather.location.region);

    return (<div className='displayer'>
        <h2>{country.name}</h2>
        <p>Capital {country.capital}</p>
        <p>Population {country.population}</p>
        <h4>Languages</h4>
        <ul>
            {country.languages.map(lang => <li key={lang.name}>{lang.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
        <img src={country.flag} alt='this is the country flag'></img>
        {/*<Weather weather={capitalWeather}/>*/}
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: can you include the definition of the `setWeather` function? Where is the data stored to the `capitalWeather` object?

Comment: also can you post the country object you are using?

Comment: Can you share setwhether() method?

Comment: `setWeather` is created with `useState`, also, it would be fine if you attach object which you are passing as argument, it looks like it needs to have `country` property inside it, also edit you answer and change `****` to property name, it'll help us

Comment: check your headers, try setting correct `Content-Type` header `application/json` or have a look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: -The variable capitalWeather is a [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html](react hook). setWeather is the equivalent to this.useState .
-country is a reference of one specified object of an array of objects got from this API CALL: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all.
- In the header, specified content-type is : "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`capitalWeather` is initialized as an array in this code.

```
  const [capitalWeather,setWeather]=useState([]);
```

`capitalWeather.location.region` for sure will throw an error because it does not have a property `location`.

Comment: I see, now I get it, It looks like useEffect() only runs after a rerender.The elements are rendered before useEffect() fetchs the data, and since the first render capitalWeather is just an empty array, thus It is gonna throw a type error.