# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, syntax-error

I use a jQuery file and I want to create a new metabox for Gutenberg.

But when I add the code to create it I got :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Here the code I try to add :

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;

const MyDocumentSettingTest = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel className="my-document-setting-plugin" title="My Panel">
        <p>My Document Setting Panel</p>
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);
```

Where can I add this code without error ?

I use Gulp 3 with `gulp-uglify-es`. I don't know if it's related.

Comment: Are you trying to use JSX? Because otherwise this is invalid syntax.

Comment: Well can I use @wordpress/scripts to convert my JSX to traditional javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to browser issue on tag misinterpretation. See this below answer for details. Use CDATA :

[Unexpected token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

[Mark this as answer if it helped]

Comment: No, that's not the issue. The issue you linked to is about HTML inside a JavaScript string literal.