# Blazor AddAuthentication disables server interactivity

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

In my .NET 8 Blazor server application, I want a login to be required first in order to use the app.

I have found out that if you set

> AddAuthorization and FallbackPolicy

, authorization is enforced unless attributes such as Authorize are set.

I am redirected to the login page in my app as expected. However, nothing happens when I click on the

> Click me

button. As soon as I comment out AddAuthorization, the debugger jumps to the method.

For global server interactivity I use:

```
<body>
  <Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
  <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
```

in App.razor

For this I use:
Program.cs

```
 public class Program
 {
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

     // Add services to the container.
     builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
            .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
     builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

     builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
             {
                 options.LoginPath = "/login";
             });
     builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
     {
         // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy  
         options.FallbackPolicy = options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                                          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                          .Build();
     });

     var app = builder.Build();

     // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
         // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
         app.UseHsts();
     }

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();

     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseAntiforgery();
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

     app.Run();
  }
}
```

Routes.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Login.razor:

```
@page "/login"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
<PageTitle>Login</PageTitle>

<h1>Login Sir!</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
  private int currentCount = 0;

  private void IncrementCount()
  {
    currentCount++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue with the error message in console:
[image]

it indicates when you send request to `blazor.web.js` you would get html codes instead of js codes for you're not authorized and fallback to "/login",here's an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) related with the error message

After check the source codes `MapRazorComponents<>()` method:

```
public static RazorComponentsEndpointConventionBuilder MapRazorComponents<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(Component)] TRootComponent>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(endpoints);

    EnsureRazorComponentServices(endpoints);
    AddBlazorWebJsEndpoint(endpoints);
    OpaqueRedirection.AddBlazorOpaqueRedirectionEndpoint(endpoints);

    return GetOrCreateDataSource<TRootComponent>(endpoints).DefaultBuilder;
}



 private static void AddBlazorWebJsEndpoint(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        var options = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(RazorComponentsEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions).Assembly),
            OnPrepareResponse = CacheHeaderSettings.SetCacheHeaders
        };

        var app = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder();
        app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            // Set endpoint to null so the static files middleware will handle the request.
            context.SetEndpoint(null);

            return next(context);
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles(options);

        var blazorEndpoint = endpoints.Map("/_framework/blazor.web.js", app.Build())
            .WithDisplayName("Blazor web static files");

        blazorEndpoint.Add((builder) => ((RouteEndpointBuilder)builder).Order = int.MinValue);

#if DEBUG
        // We only need to serve the sourcemap when working on the framework, not in the distributed packages
        endpoints.Map("/_framework/blazor.web.js.map", app.Build())
            .WithDisplayName("Blazor web static files sourcemap")
            .Add((builder) => ((RouteEndpointBuilder)builder).Order = int.MinValue);
#endif
    }
```

I think the static webasset `<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>` was blocked by [Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#static-file-authorization)

Why not try with the codes in routes.razor for you blazor app?

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)"  >
    <NotAuthorized>
        Not authorized
    </NotAuthorized>
 </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Could you share your further requirement?